# How do I customize the context menu in Nemo?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I recently installed nemo 4.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and quite happy with it. However I find the context menu bothered me a little. There's no shortcut label on the right of menu like Nautilus. The width of menu also inconsistent. Sometimes it has proportional width, sometimes too narrow.

[nemo-context-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6888F.jpg)

Can I add / show that shortcut and set fixed width?. Thank you!.

Comment: It seems to be GTK3 bug, not Nemo's. I'm seeing this with Caja too.